# Race Condition in React setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, race-condition

**The Problem:**

Multiple children of a component are having events triggered near simultaneously.  Each of these events are handled by `handleChange` style functions which use React's immutability helpers to merge complex objects into the state of the controlling component, via something similar to;

```
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {$merge: new_value_object}));
```

This works fine when the events trigger independently, but when multiple events cause updates to the state in this way, each is individually merging from the *old* version of the state.  I.e. (psuedo-code, not intended to execute).

```
function logState() { console.log(this.state) }

logState(); // {foo: '', bar: ''}

var next_value_object_A = {foo: '??'}
var next_value_object_B = {bar: '!!'}

this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {$merge: new_value_object_A}),
    logState); 
this.setState(React.addons.update(this.state, {$merge: new_value_object_B}),
    logState);
```

Would produce;

```
{foo: '??', bar: ''}
{foo: '', bar: '!!'}
```

**Terrible solution that I don't want to use:**

The following seems to work, but also seems to be a *major* anti-pattern;

```
setSynchronousState: function(nextState){
    this.state = React.addons.update(this.state, {$merge: nextState});
    this.setState(this.state);
}
```

This relies on modifying the State directly.  I don't see any immediate problems in running this code, and it does solve the problem at hand, but I have to imagine that I'm inheriting some massive technical debt with this solution.

A slightly better version of this solution is;

```
getInitialState: function(){
    this._synchronous_state = //Something
    return this._synchronous_state;
},

_synchronous_state: {},

setSynchronousState: function(nextState){
   this._synchronous_state = React.addons.update(this._synchronous_state, {$merge: nextState});
   this.setState(this._synchronous_state);
}
```

Which successfully avoids touching `this.state` directly, though now we have the issue of conflicting information being passed around the application.  Each other function now needs to be congnizant of whether it is accessing `this.state` or `this._synchronous_state`.

**The Question:**

Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you setting state as an update of state? Just set state directly: `this.setState({someKey: 'someVal'});` This solves your race issue, lowers the size of your package, and makes your code much simpler to read. The `update` addon is meant to be used on immutable objects. A component's state is not an immutable object - it is a normal JS object that may or may not contain immutable objects.

Comment: React docs claim that the state should be treated as an immutable object.  The merging is being done as a means to set fields dynamically from multiple sources, rather than having 50ish unique `handleChange` functions in one component to handle the large number of potential user inputs associated.

Comment: The key word there is *thought of*. It is not however an `immutable.js` object. You should never modify `this.state` directly, only via `this.setState()`

Comment: Ok, that's not really answering the question at all though... I know it's not actually immutable (my solution demonstrates that pretty clearly).  The question is how to better address concurrent setState calls.

Comment: Except that isn't true... from the docs: ["setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains."](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Answering my own question in case anyone else ever sees this;

`this.setState` can take in a function as it's argument, rather than an object, which looks like this;

```
this.setState(function(state){ 
    ...
    return newState 
});
```

Which allows you to access the current state (at time of execution) via the passed argument to that function.